# Trying to parse a string entry into a double but the point for the decimal is never recognized

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

There's multiple threads on this where they say to play with CultureInfo but nothing worked for me.

I have a Xamarin.Forms App, the user enters a value that is a string and which can be either written 90, 90.1 or 90,9. Then the value is converted to double to do some calculations.

The xamarin entry component has the attributes "Numeric" so the user can only enter numbers and a point or comma depending on the language of the device.

Since i didn't know in the first place that the language mattered for the point or comma this was my first implementation:

```
public static double CalculateExposition(TasksGroup group)
{
    return Math.Round(10 * Math.Log10(group.Taches.Sum(x =>
        GetDuration(x.TaskDuration).TotalHours * Math.Pow(10, double.Parse(x.TaskDBA.Replace(",", ".")) / 10.0)) / 8), 1);
}
```

You can see more details under, thanks a lot for your help.

**Problem**

This was working all fine with a french emulator on VS 2017 ( somehow i had no keyboard restriction and could do comma and point) until i upgraded my app from vs 2017 to 2019 and tested with an english emulator which uses . for decimal point.

The point is NEVER recognized when i try with an english emulator, so if i put 90.9 it will be recognized like 909.

**What i tried (in all threads they say to use CultureInfo but it doesn't do anything for me)**

One of the other thing i tried is implementing a custom renderer for the keyboard which was allowing the user to use , or . but apparently i need it to be based on language.

```
public static double CalculateExposition(TasksGroup group)
{
    return Math.Round(10 * Math.Log10(group.Taches.Sum(x =>
        GetDuration(x.TaskDuration).TotalHours * Math.Pow(10, double.Parse(x.TaskDBA.Replace(",", "."), NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) / 10.0)) / 8), 1);
}
```

Comment: The current culture should reflect what the user is used to (assuming Xamarin is like working on Windows, the current culture reflects the user's settings).  If you really want to accept both `90.1` and `90,1`, use `double.TryParse` (which, by the way is always a good idea when dealing with user input).  Do it once with one culture, if it fails, do it with another.  However, be wary about this.  The comma is used as a thousands separator in most English cultures.  I believe that the dot is used as a thousands separator in some cultures

Comment: What is your `CurrentCulture`?

Comment: @N.Dogac fr-CA when emulator in french and en-US in english but they want the app to work for most language but i think this will be the two main used since were in quebec canada.

Comment: Ah, Quebec (where I'm from, originally).  I understand why you need to accept either culture - Canada is majority English (and use en-CA) while Quebec is majority French and uses fr-CA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this extension method:

```
static class StringExtensions
    {
        private static readonly CultureInfo Fr = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");

        public static decimal ToDecimal(this string value)
        {
            if (value.Contains(','))
                return decimal.Parse(value, Fr);

            return decimal.Parse(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
    }
```

If the input string contains a comma then parse it using the French culture. If not, it will be containing a dot or nothing. So parsing it with `InvariantCulture` (English culture) will do.

Comment: You are probably better off looking for a dot (`.`) rather than a comma.  As I mentioned, English cultures (like en-US and en-CA) use a comma as a thousands separator.  As far as I know (from usage, not from looking at the specification), fr-CA uses a space as a thousands separator.  I still think using `TryParse` with two different cultures is probably the better solution

Comment: @N. Dogac i wanna try this but i am not too familiar with extensions method and how to implement it.  Do i just create a new class and how do i use it then for my function ? Also, will decimal really work since i am doing calculation ? in my project i just tried to test with decimal.Parse and get a lot of "cannot divide decimal by double. Thanks.

Comment: @Flydog57 You got a point. But I've never seen any thousands seperators used in numbers throughout my career. I think this method will work fine most of the cases. But as you said, if the number contains thousands seperators then it may not work.

Comment: @codetime: The `decimal` type is more exact than the `double` type (for example, if you are creating an application that works with money, use `decimal`).  But, you are using `Math.Log10` and `Math.Pow`, so you need to be using `double`.  Don't bother with `decimal`.  Creating extension methods is easy.  The documentation should be pretty clear.  Bonne chance!